# lsmeans contrast for interaction term

Tags: r, lsmeans

I'm attempting use `lsmeans` and its contrast for an F-test on an interaction. Basically, I'd like to replicate what Stata does with its `contrast` command. I'd like to do this for two reasons:

1. within a regression model that has an interaction between factor variables;
2. within an ANOVA to help decompose a three-way interaction.

For this question, I'll ask about the three-way interaction.

```
library(haven)
threeway <- read_spss("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/threeway.sav")
threeway$ID <- row.names(threeway)

library(afex)
three_fit <- aov_ez("ID", "y", data = threeway, between = c("a", "b", "c"))
three_fit

> three_fit
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: y
  Effect    df  MSE          F ges p.value
1      a 1, 12 1.33 112.50 *** .90  <.0001
2      b 1, 12 1.33       0.50 .04     .49
3      c 2, 12 1.33  47.84 *** .89  <.0001
4    a:b 1, 12 1.33 120.13 *** .91  <.0001
5    a:c 2, 12 1.33     6.84 * .53     .01
6    b:c 2, 12 1.33    8.47 ** .59    .005
7  a:b:c 2, 12 1.33    6.97 ** .54    .010
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The three-way interaction is significant. Now, from the [UCLA page on Stata](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-understand-a-three-way-interaction-in-anova-stata-12/), Stata can use the code:

```
contrast b#c@a
```

This will produce an F-test for the b*c interaction at the levels of a.

I'm trying to do the same thing with `lsmeans` in R. But, I just can't get it. Here's what I've tried:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsm <- lsmeans(three_fit, c("b", "c"), by="a")
test(contrast(lsm, "consec"), joint=TRUE)
```

That gets me an F-test, but it is not correct (or at least it is not the one I want). Any help in replicating the Stata results would be appreciated. I'd really like to stay within `lsmeans` to do this, but if something else works, I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is

```
test(contrast(lsm, interaction = "consec"), joint=TRUE)
```

That is, you want to test interaction contrasts, not comparisons among means. You can see what it is you're testing (I recommend that!) by running that `contrast` call without wrapping it in `test`. Try it with and without the `interaction` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but this only gets me one F-test results (oddly with 2, 12 df). I'm looking for one interaction F-test (each with 2,12 df) for each level of "a".

Comment: Did you try adding `by="a"` to the `test` call?